# Twitter incorrect signature(401)

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am new to twitter application. I am using php   twitter api code for getting creditinals

but i got response like Array ( [request] => /account/verify_credentials.json [error] => Incorrect signature )

Any body please help me how to solve this problem

My code is

---

```
$twitterObj = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
$twitterObj->setToken($_GET['oauth_token']);
$token = $twitterObj->getAccessToken();
$twitterObj->setToken($token->oauth_token, $token->oauth_token_secret);
$twitterInfo = $twitterObj->get_accountVerify_credentials();

    print_r($twitterInfo->response);
    exit;
```

This code working fine in my local server after move to live server i got  this problem

Please help Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If it works on the local machine but not the remote server then the time on the remote server is probably out of sync. If it is more the 5 minutes off from UTC Twitter's servers will refuse the requests. You can have the time automatically sync with [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).